# How to export Prometheus metrics from GCE into stack driver

Tags: prometheus, google-stackdriver

We currently have some software that contains Prometheus data on a GCE. The said GCE already has the legacy logging agent using fluentD running, this is currently incompatible with the google ops agent according to google (we tried).

We also tried running another GCE with just the ops agent trying to pull the prom data off this vm with the application but it seems not readable. I’m not sure if it’s some specific remote read configuration or something in Prometheus.

The purpose I am doing this is we are moving away from the legacy on premise hosted alerting stuff, putting this system on gcp, and trying to export the metrics into google logging so we can script up some basic monitoring.

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated